# Share title, image and description using FBSDK for IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, fbsdk

Im just start using Facebook idk for iOS and want to allow users share image,title and description from my app, something like this :

[image]

But I only get the title and description :s this is my code:

```
let imageType: FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: self.GenerateMapImage("\(latitude)",lng: "\(longitude)") , userGenerated: false)
            //let imageType2: FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: UIImage(named: alertObj.id) , userGenerated: false)
            //
            imageType.caption = alertObj.alertType[0].name

            let content: FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
            let contentProp = ["og:type":"name_space:alert","og:title":"#\(name) \(addressName)","og:url" : "http://www.url.com"  , "og:description": description, "place:location:latitude":"\(latitude)", "place:location:longitude":"\(longitude)", "name_space:location:latitude":"\(latitude)", "name_space:location:longitude":"\(longitude)", "og:data:name_space:location:latitude":"\(latitude)", "og:data:name_space:location:longitude":"\(longitude)", "al:web:url" : "http://www.url.com"  ]

            let graphObj: FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: contentProp)
            graphObj.setArray([imageType], forKey: "og:image")

           // graphObj.setPhoto(imageType, forKey: "og:image")

            let facebookShare:FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
            let fbAction: FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
            facebookShare.delegate = alertActionsIntance
            fbAction.setArray([imageType], forKey: "og:image")
            fbAction.setObject(graphObj, forKey: "alert")
            fbAction.actionType = "name_space:share"

            content.action = fbAction
            content.previewPropertyName = "alert"

            facebookShare.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Automatic
            facebookShare.shareContent = content;
            facebookShare.fromViewController = alertController;
            facebookShare.show()
```

Also this is my app configuration:

[image: Object configuration]
[image: Attachements]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using `FBSDKSharePhoto`. If you can use a image url, just put it as an string entry into your `contentProp` dictionary like `"og:image":IMAGE_URL` and it will show as a thumbnail.

This has worked for me

```
NSDictionary *properties  = @{
                                 @"og:type": @"",
                                 @"og:title":@"",
                                 @"og:description": @"",
                                 @"og:url":@"",
                                 @"og:image":@""
                            };


}
//Create an object
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];
// Create an action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"";
[action setObject:object forKey:@""];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"";

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:self];
```

Comment: Hi, I have tested adding the image as string but still not working, I have add it  to the action as: fbAction.setString(imageUrl, forKey: "og:image")

Comment: I edited my answer above to reflect what has worked for me. Hope it helps